# "git svn" command fails with error "git: 'svn' is not a git command. See 'git --help'."

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I am trying to execute this command on my redhat 6.5 box and it throws the error "git: 'svn' is not a git command. See 'git --help'." I have git 1.7.1 installed on this box. Please help.

git svn clone http://yourcompany.com/path/to/svn/project-abc project-abc

Answer (score 27):

you need to have the `git-svn` package installed (this is a separate package).